# How to know how many parameters a method is expecting?

Tags: php, oop, reflection

Using, probably, the ReflectionClass, how could I know how many parameters is a method expecting?

```
class Test {
    public function mymethod($one, $two, $three = '') {}
    public function anothermethod($four) {}
}

$test = new Test();
$i = function_im_looking_for(array($test, 'mymethod'));
$i2 = function_im_looking_for(array($test, 'anothermethod'));
echo $i .' - '. $i2;
```

The above code should output : `3 - 1`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function function_im_looking_for($callable) {
    list($class, $method) = $callable;
    $reflector = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
    return $reflector->getNumberOfParameters();
}
```

It's all just about finding [`ReflectionMethod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getParameters()` method of refelectClass and then count it something like:

```
$refMethod = new ReflectionMethod('className',  'functionName');
$params = $refMethod->getParameters();
echo count($params);
```

#### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/84UZ1Aq5)